# T-SQL Not Performing Arithmetic Calculation of Aggregates Correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregates

I have a table variable that stores the average times for two separate sub tasks that is grouped by employee. I need to add a record that stores the calculated weighted averages for those two tasks for the entire company.

I added a column that stores the average times it took each employee to commit each subtask and then multiplied it by the number of total tasks that employee performed.

I populate the table with the records for each employee through the following query:

```
 DECLARE @TotalNumberTasks INT
        ,@CompanyName VARCHAR(50) = 'Company ABC'

SELECT @TotalNumberTasks = COUNT(*) FROM Tbl1 --2436

INSERT INTO @OutputTemp
(
    EmployeeID
    ,EmployeeName 
    ,AverageTimeSubTask1
    ,AverageTimeSubTask2
    ,NumberTasks
    ,SqlComputedSubTask1WeightedNumber
    ,SqlComputedSubTask2WeightedNumber
) 
SELECT TaskPerformedByUserID
        ,TaskPerformedByUserName
        ,AVG(CAST(SubTask1Time AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
        ,AVG(CAST(SubTask2Time  AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
        ,COUNT(*)
        ,AVG(CAST(SubTask1Time AS DECIMAL(6,2))) * COUNT(*)
        ,AVG(CAST(SubTask2Time  AS DECIMAL(6,2))) * COUNT(*)
FROM Tbl1
GROUP BY TaskPerformedByUserID, TaskPerformedByUserName
```

Once I have that information I use the following query to add the desired company aggregate row:

```
INSERT INTO @OutputTemp
(
    EmployeeID
    ,EmployeeName 
    ,AverageTimeSubTask1
    ,AverageTimeSubTask2 
)
SELECT  NULL
        ,@CompanyName
        ,SUM(CAST(SqlComputedSubTask1WeightedNumber AS DECIMAL(6,2)))/@TotalNumberTasks
        ,SUM(CAST(SqlComputedSubTask2WeightedNumber AS DECIMAL(6,2)))/@TotalNumberTasks
FROM @OutputTemp
```

The issue I'm facing is that the weighted value for each employee to get the company averages is being incorrectly calculated. I included two additional columns in the following example table structure example showing the correct values.

[image]

I'm mystified as to why this is happening. I understand that the division will result in the loss of information after the decimal when each number is rounded down but that's ok. The issue is it's not rounding down to the correct integer in some cases.

Furthermore, the calculations aren't even being made consistently. For example, on the record for Employee1, the same exact calculation is being performed (.06*145) and it results in two seperate values of 7 and 8.

I looked around and thought the issue may be related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818719/sql-server-percentage-calculation-not-calculating-correctly%5C), but when I tried converting the denominator to a float type as suggested I got the exact same results.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is the initial table variable declaration for @OutputTemp I was using:

```
DECLARE @OutputTemp TABLE
(
    EmployeeID INT
    ,EmployeeName VARCHAR(75)
    ,AverageTimeSubTask1 DECIMAL(6,2) 
    ,AverageTimeSubTask2 DECIMAL(6,2)
    ,NumberTasks INT
    ,SqlComputedSubTask1WeightedNumber INT
    ,SqlComputedSubTask2WeightedNumber INT
)
```

Here is the modified table variable structure that clarified the issue.

```
  DECLARE @OutputTemp TABLE
(
    EmployeeID INT
    ,EmployeeName VARCHAR(75)
    ,AverageTimeSubTask1 DECIMAL(10,8) 
    ,AverageTimeSubTask2 DECIMAL(10,8)
    ,NumberTasks INT
    ,SqlComputedSubTask1WeightedNumber INT
    ,SqlComputedSubTask2WeightedNumber INT
)
```

Because I was using a type definition for `AverageTimeSubTask1` & `AverageTimeSubTask2` that was limiting the scale of the value to two decimal places, I was mistaking the value in the temp variable as what was used in the calculation, as mentioned by @WolfgangKais.

Here is the resulting `@OutputTemp` structure after changing the precision & scale for the two average sub task times:

[image]

As you can see, the calculations are indeed being performed correctly.

Comment: where do you declare the table variable @OutputTemp? Where is the DDL+DML for the table Tbl1?!? How do you want us to execute this query if we don't have these?

Comment: You are speaking of "the exact same calculation" when multiplying 0.06 by 145, but in fact two numbers that display as 0.06 are multiplied by 145. What are the results of `AVG` before saving them in the `@OutputTemp`? These are the values multiplied by 145.

Comment: @WolfgangKais You were exactly right. I was mistaking what was being displayed as .06 in the average sub task times due to the incorrect decimal scale used in the table variable declaration as the true value being used. The underlying values (idk what the right word for them is) were what was used when calculating the weighted numbers for each subtask.

Comment: @RonenAriely I didn't think them necessary for an answer but I was wrong. The fact I didn't originally use the right precision/ scale for my decimal type fields in the table variable is what was causing me to misinterpret what was going on. I'll post the original & modified versions for anyone who may come across this question down the road.

Comment: Hi @W.Harr, I am back, but the question does not show any improvement. Yes, It is necessary to post everything that we need in order to reproduce the issue, which you still did not publish. You need to remember that we cannot read mind (at least not me) and you should explain your issue from the start to end in orderly way. Instead of waste two/three hours to understand what you need and what you have we can help 10 more people at that time! I tried to read your question again but once more, it is not clear and not organized....

Comment: You started with some stories and than you provide code that "`INSERT INTO @OutputTemp`" but we have no information about the table variable yet... I keep reading and I found two declaration of the table variable. I have no idea what you mean by "`modified table variable structure`". A table variable cannot be altered... at this point I stopped reading... try please to start with what what you have in the database now (queries to create the relevant elements) stop using table variables if you are talking about tables in the database. These elements does not behave the same...

Answer (score 0):

To start with, before getting deeper into troubleshooting, I would do ensure that no nulls are interfering with my dataset and only quality data is being processed:

In INSERT INTO @OutputTemp query add this condition in select : WHERE Employee is Not Null

Also, I would declare @OutputTemp table beforehand with appropriate column types so that I don't have to cast values last minute.

Answer (score 0):

1) just have one end as decimal(14,4) for example, count returns INT which is lower in type precedence and SQL will do a cast up to decimal to match to the highest type.

2) Float and Real are not precise types, so you'll never get as accurate as decimal with at least 4 decimals as I suggested in my previous point.

Try this:

```
SELECT TaskPerformedByUserID
        ,TaskPerformedByUserName
        ,cast(COUNT(*) as decimal(14,4))/(select count(*) from Tbl1) * 100 percent_to_total
FROM Tbl1
GROUP BY TaskPerformedByUserID, TaskPerformedByUserName
```